# Estimating the norm of inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I am interesting in estimating the norm of the inverse of a real square matrix $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, which is defined by
$$\|A^{-1}\|=\sup_{u\in \mathbb R^n}\frac{\|A^{-1}u\|}{\|u\|}$$

My idea is to search for the vectors $v_i\in \mathbb R^n$ such that
$$Av_i=\vec e_i,\qquad i=1,2,...n$$
and then estimating the norm as 
$$S(A)=\sup_i \|v_i\|$$

**Is it true that there exists a constant $c$ depending only on the dimension of the matrix such that**
$$\|A^{-1}\|\le cS(A)?$$

Comment: You want to estimate the norm of the inverse in terms of what?

Comment: I am reformulating the question @lcv

Comment: @lcv Is it more clear now?

Comment: Not really. What are the vectors $v_i$ and $e_i$? How can the norm of the vectors $v_i$ depend on $A$?